# Getting error in running .net webservice on IIS 7 on dedicated server

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis-7, publishing

I have made C# webservice in asp.net 2008 with 3.5 framework. I made this webservice on my local machine.

Now i tried to run this webservice on client's dedicated server using IIS7(on client's server). But it gives me an error -

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have just added my locally published webervice and other files in IIS and then tried to run it , but not been successfull.

How can i do it ?

I have no idea about this thing.

What are the steps to perform this task?

What are the changes to  be made in Web.Config file ?

Please help me out..

Thanks.

Comment: make sure you published it correctly check the folder on the server to make sure all of it dependencies are there you can also copy object bin and properties directly to the folder where you publish your project

Comment: @COLDTOLD - thanks for reply. I have copied my published webservice's folder(which contains config, webservice ,bin and other files) in "C:inerpub\wwwroot\" on IIS. Then i added this folder on IIS (by right clicking on default website in IIS) by specifying path of "C:inerpub\wwwroot\".

Comment: @Rohan mark at least one answer as accepted if issue resolved. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should install on your server the ASP.NET AJAX for Asp.Net You can find it here and select the .NET 3.5 version of the toolkit: [http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/87024](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=883)

If you don't have access in this server, you can upload the .dll file into the BIN folder.

I hope it works! Cheers

Comment: thanks for reply. I want to know should i make any changes in web.config file of my .net werbsevie ?

Comment: you are welcome, but first install the ajax on server and than host the services again. After these browse the services and see what will happen.

Comment: thanks again. As you and Asif suggested to install Ajax on server. But i want to know , i am not using any ajax control in my webservice. so should i required to install it?

Comment: If your are not using any ajax control than remove the references and there is no need to install ajax extension and in other case you used ajax controls than u have to install ajax extension. Asif already told you man.......

Comment: Oh.! Ok. I have not used any ajax control. so i do not need to install ajax. But i want to know , there are many references of "Syste.Web.Extensions" available in config file. so should i remove all the references ?

Comment: yes, take a backup of ur config file first, and than remove the references, and restart the services

Comment: @Talha- I have removed all references of "System.Web.Extensions" and republished it. Now it gives an error "HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found.The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler."

Comment: http://blog.rapiddg.com/2009/11/asmx-will-not-be-served-by-the-static-file-handler-resolution/ follow this link

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Install web extension on your server.

OR

install ASP.NET 2.0 AJAX Extensions 1.0 http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=883

Comment: thanks for reply. What is web extension ? i dont have any idea of it.

Comment: if you are using any ajax Microsoft control then you need this and it will solve your problem.

Comment: ok. And i want to know, should i make any changes in my webservice's web.config file ?

Comment: if you are not using any ajax control then you will simply remove the reference of System.Web.Extension from web.config

Comment: No i am not using any ajax control. I have just used "Newtonsoft.Json.Net35.dll". Should i remove all the references of "System.Web.Extension" in web.config file? because there are many references available. will not affect my webservice of removing these references ?

Comment: ok take a back up of web.config and then remove the references.

Comment: I have removed all references of "System.Web.Extensions" and republished it. Now it gives an error "HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found.The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler."

Comment: try this link https://dnnsupport.dnn4less.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/277/0/http-error-40417---not-found